# Как работает vector?

Tags: c++

Почему пример ниже выводит 6?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        static int cnt;
        A(int a){}
        ~A(){cnt++;}
};
int A::cnt = 0;

int main()
{
    vector <A> a(4,1);
    a.push_back(1);
    cout << A::cnt;
    //cout << a.size();
}
```

Если убрать push_back, то выводит 1. 
Верно я понимаю, что вектор при инициализации и добавлении элементов выделяет в куче память для них, создаёт каждый элемент по отдельности, копирует его в это место и удаляет из этого места?

1. Зачем так сложно? Почему он сразу не создаст эти элементы в выделенной для себя памяти?
2. И даже если я верно сформулировал мысль, не понимаю, почему в 1м примере результат = 6, а не 5

Comment: Замените `push_back` на `emplace_back`, и посмотрите...

Comment: Лучше отметьте конструктор `A(int a)` как `explicit`

Comment: Вы создаёте экземпляр класса `A`, который передаёте в конструктор класса `vector`, и который потом надо удалить. Тоже самое с `push_back`. Также, когда классу `vector` необходимо переместить внутренние хранилище (для увеличения его размера), он удаляет элементы из предыдущего места хранения. Итого два экземпляра `A` удаляете Вы (переданные в конструктор и `push_back`) и четыре удаляет `vector` при изменении размера. Всего получается шесть.

Comment: Harry, будет 5 :) все стало ещё запутаннее. Emplace вроде добавляет элемент в конец вектора без изменения указателя на сам вектор? Тогда и лишнего копирования ж не должно быть? И по идее результат должен быть равен двум?

Comment: @PetSerAl, звучит логично. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: Попробуйте переопределить у класса конструкторы копирования и перемещения, чтобы все конструкторы что-то писали в консоль. И выводить не только конечный результат, а промежуточные шаги. Вы точно ничего не перепутали, считая количество вызовов деструктора?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Для создания вектора вы воспользовались конструктром

   ```
   vector(size_type count, сonst T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
   ```

   то есть ваше

   ```
   vector <A> a(4, 1);
   ```

   эквивалентно

   ```
   vector <A> a(4, A(1), std::allocator<A>());
   ```

   Последующее уничтожение неявно созданного вами временного объекта `A(1)` дало вам первый вызов деструктора.
2. Для добавления нового элемента в вектор вы сделали

   ```
   a.push_back(1);
   ```

   что эквивалентно

   ```
   a.push_back(A(1));
   ```

   Уничтожение этого временного объекта `A(1)` дало вам еще один вызов деструктора.
3. При добавлении объекта в вектор произошло перевыделение памяти вектора с перемещением содержимого уже существовавших четырех объектов на новое место, после чего старые объекты были уничтожены. Это еще 4 вызова деструкторов.

Итого - 6 вызовов деструкторов.

---

> Зачем так сложно? Почему он сразу не создаст эти элементы в выделенной для себя памяти?

А почему именно так? Здесь возможны две очевидные стратегии: 1) использовать предоставленный инициализатор `1` для независимого создания 4 целевых объектов `A`, 2) сначала создать самостоятельный временный объект-образец типа `A`, а затем скопировать его 4 раза в вектор.

Кто вам сказал, что первый способ лучше второго? Дизайнеры стандартной библиотеки считают по-другому. (Или по крайней мере вынужденно считали тогда, когда в С++ не было средств форвардинга аргументов.) Очевидно, что при более-менее "тяжелой" конструкции, проще сконструировать сложный объект один раз и потом несколько раз скопировать готовое, чем снова и снова конструировать объекты с нуля.

Когда же вы добавляли один-единственный элемент в вектор, никто вас не заставлял идти по пути `push_back` с созданием промежуточного объекта. Вы могли сделать

```
a.emplace_back(1);
```

и действительно создать новый объект напрямую на месте.

Comment: Спасибо, так понятнее. Но разве в с++ нет контейнера, который бы просто хранил адреса на объекты в куче и при изменении размера копировал бы только адреса на уже существующие объекты, не уничтожая их, добавив новый адрес в новый список на новый и аллоцировал только непосредственно тот объект, который добавлен? Мне кажется, так было бы оптимальнее?

Comment: @Александр: Тип элемента контейнера выбирается исключительно вами самими. Хотите хранить адреса? Пожалуйста - храните адреса. У вас здесь есть полная свобода выбора. В этом примере вы ясно сказали контейнеру, что будете хранить в нем именно сами объекты, а не адреса.